# AddClientCertificate method on Connection not found in signalr 1.1 beta

Tags: signalr

AddClientCertificate() on Connection not found in signalr 1.1 beta. Downloaded and installed  nuget package to solution using the below command

```
  PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -Pre
```

The signalr client.dll details are as below 
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client(16757...) 
File Version 1.1.20410.0 
Product Version 1.1.0-beta1.

Unable to locate connection.AddClientCertificate() method

Please help where to download the latest signalr 1.1 beta version that has AddClientCertificate method on hub connection?

Thanks in advance.
Priya

Answer (score 1):

You're installing the wrong package:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client -Pre
```

Comment: Thanks David. I have installed the same package. But could not find connection.AddClientCertificate method.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not seeing this either.  I'm using SignalR 1.1.0 released with Visual Studio 2010.  I just searched throughout the entire list in the Object Browser.   I can't find anything under Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client

Comment: This is better put in comments, rather than an answer/